# How to return compiled main.ts script with vite

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I want to compile the main.ts and return the resulting script, to use it on a third party website.
I want the script to be ready to run.
Now when I access localhost I get a 404 or cannot GET error depending on how I run vite (just vite or vite preview).

Here my vite.config.ts now:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        outDir: 'dist',
        minify: 'terser',
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
                exports: 'named'
            }
        },
        terserOptions: {
            compress: {
                drop_console: true,
                drop_debugger: true
            }
        },
        lib: {
            formats: ['umd', 'es'],
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.ts'),
            name: 'Widget',
            fileName: format => 'widget.${format}.js'
        }
   },
   resolve: {
       extensions: ['.ts', '.json', '.vue'],
       alias: [{
          find: '@',
          replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src')
       }]
   },
   server: {
       https: false,
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 3000
   }
})
```

vite.config.ts + main.ts